# Global prototypes for big solutions (JavaScript/Node)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prototype, es6-modules

Is there any best practice to write prototypes for classes like Array, Number, etc. for global scope in modular JavaScript?

For example I have a ***create-react-app*** application and i want to find any good way to add prototypes to global scope.

**arrayHelpers.js**

```
Array.prototype.unique = () => {
   //... some code
};
```

**SomeComponent.js**

```
export default const SomeComponent = () => {
   const someArray = ["foo", "bar", "foo"];
   const someArrayThatHasOnlyUniqueItems = someArray.unique(); // ["foo", bar"]

   // ... more code 
};
```

I don't want to use classic functions like *unique(array)*, because prototypes are much cleaner and easier to use.

Also, importing any file into every single component is not the best way to do that.

Comment: Hello, RadekDeveloper. Extending a native object prototype is a bad practice. I strongly suggest you to not do this.

Comment: the best practice is not to do it at all but each to own, what are you stuck on your defining it, does it not work?

Comment: @AhmetCanGüven What's bad about extending native object prototypes?

Comment: `importing any file into every single component is not the best way to do that` yes, yes it is.

Comment: Extending native object prototypes is a lose-lose situation. Either your code becomes widespread and you've essentially condemned a keyword without consensus. Or your code doesn't and it's at risk of breaking if the specs use your keyword.

Comment: @RadekDeveloper 1. it can cause naming conflicts with other libraries. 2. It can prevent or make difficult official extensions of the Javascript language (see 1). 3. It is confusing to other developers, including your future self. Just google it. Then never do it.

Comment: It's how the internet breaks: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/smooshgate

Comment: @RadekDeveloper why would you need to shift to Typescript for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending native prototypes is very frowned upon. [This is how you break the internet!](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/smooshgate)

You could create a custom Array type by extending the existing one (in which case you'll have to import your custom Array in every file you need to create one):

```
class MyArray extends Array {
  function unique() {
    //...
  }
}
const someArray = new MyArray("foo", "bar")
```

You could extend the Symbols prototype of Array (in which case you'll have to import your Symbol in every file you need to use the function):

```
const unique = new Symbol('unique')
Array.prototype[unique] = () => { ... }
// ...
someArray[unique]()
```

But probably the best way to do it would be to simply make it a pure standalone function:

```
function unique(array) {
  // ...
}
unique(someArray)
```

Yes it is boring, like most good code should be.

Yes it isn't as sugary (but if you like sugar, you could always write your own Babel plugin).

Yes you have to import it everywhere (most JS projects have a lot of imports on every file).

Yes this is the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion! Making own plugin is a thing that i will think about!